# Can you start a thread and a process in the same code?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

1. Can a main method of the code spin up a new thread and a new process? Please look at the main method in the below sample code for clarification of the question
2. If the answer to the previous questions is yes: In that case the data object modified by the thread when passed to the process, will it need to be a deepcopy of the object ? Or can it be referenced directly since it is a part of the parent main process?

P.S. The following code behaves as expected. The question is around if this is an acceptable solution? Or if there are some edge cases or obvious issues with the following code, that I might be overlooking

```py
import threading
from multiprocessing import process
from copy import deepcopy
from threading import Lock
import time

class ABC:
    def __init__(self, lock):
        self.object = []
        self.lock = lock
    def modify_list(self):
        while condition_true:
            self._modify_list()
            time.sleep(few_minutes)

    def _modify_list(self):
        with self.lock:
            ''' Does something to modify self.object'''
class XYZ:
    def __init__(self, abc_obj):
        self.abc_obj = abc_obj
    def read_obj(self):
        ''' Performs the read operation on the abc_obj'''

def main():
    lock = Lock()
    abc = ABC(lock)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=abc.modify_list)
    t1.start()

    while condition_true:
        with lock:
            xyz = XYZ(deepcopy(abc.object))
        p1 = process.Process(target=xyz.read_obj)
        p1.start()
        p1.join()
    t1.join()
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Both parts of your question are not well posed. It might be easier to point you the "right question" (and its answer) if you explained exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why would you assume that you could not start both a process and thread? Why would you assume that creating a deep copy *before* starting a process is needed?

Comment: If you look at the main() method, I am trying to spin a thread and a process from the same function. Are there any issues with this approach?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I tried running it without a deepcopy and that did not work, that is the reason for the deepcopy of the object.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Did it throw an exception? Did it not behave as expected?

Comment: It did not read the updated values in the list (i.e  not behave as expected)

Comment: The `Process` in this case is a red herring I think. Does your `ABC.modify_list` have any kind of thread synchronization? You need some kind of locks around it so that your main thread isn't trying the read the object at the same time that your ancillary thread is modifying it. The fact that after you read `ABC.object` you pass it as an argument to a routine in a subprocess is irrelevant.

Comment: Since processes do not share memory, what the thread does to ``abc`` in the initial process is not necessarily visible in the child process. Only if the thread finishes before the process is launched does the later inherit the data from the former.

Comment: @Iguananaut thank you for pointing out the lock situation. I do have a lock in the original code in the main thread before it tries to make a copy of the list. 
And my main concern was regarding spinning a process with the thread, since I couldn't find any documentation or code for the same

Comment: @MisterMiyagi agreed. This question is under the assumption that the thread has modified the list before the process starts

Comment: I think the synchronisation details matter, and it would help to know exactly what you expect this code to do and what it's doing instead.

Comment: @Iguananaut Please read the modified code that has the synchronization in place
Also, this code is behaving as I expect it to, but my question was around if there are some edge cases that I am missing? Or if there is some obvious issues or alternative solutions to this? (except for spinning up 2 threads)

Comment: Again, I think it would help if you explained exactly what you are hoping to achieve, since without a complete picture it's not possible to just guess what your problem is.

Comment: Regardless the updated code makes a little more sense now. Assuming your data structure *can* be deepcopied it makes sense to do so here since you want to grab a snapshot of it to pass to the subprocess. You could also avoid that by holding the lock while starting the Process but it would be better not to as that would block your thread that much longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding first question: yes you can create a thread to perform some task while the main thread creates a process, or more threads... I don't see why that should be a problem to you. When you create a thread, the thread will jump to the thread target and the main thread will continue with the next instruction, which can happen to be creating a process.

For the second question, if you don't set a shared memory page for the child process, all the process memory is "deep copied" (quotes apply since it's actually a copy-on-write) and so the new process will not be aware of what the thread did to the object, because there will be a new copy of everything, including the object.

However, you're facing yourself a race condition: since the thread can modify the object, it will depend on the exact moment where the new process is created that it will have the new or old value. No matter what, any further changes done by other threads will not be seen by the new process.

If you do set a shared memory page ([multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html)), then the child process will actually see all the changes done by the thread.

Comment: I only care about the object at the point when the process was created, if it is modified post creation it doesn't matter to the process. In this case, what would be recommended, creating a shared_memory or deepcopy?

Comment: Make a deepcopy, but make it before the thread starts, so once it's modified by the thread it still works, otherwise it's useless since when you call deepcopy it is possible that the thread has already modified the object. No need of shared memory in your case.

Comment: I need the most up to date modification by the thread when the process starts, so I think in my case I will need to make deepcopy every time I spin up a process inside the loop to get the latest value of the list